# "Android L" Loading Spinner CSS

Tags: html, css

After looking at Google's new [/design](http://www.google.com/design/), I was wondering if there's any way to accomplish a loading spinner like the one under [/progress-activity](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-types-of-indicators) (Scroll down to "Circular") with HTML / CSS?

I'm only talking about the animation itself. As far as I know it might be next to impossible to round the borders of the spinner like Google did.

I only managed to do a very (very) simple version of this spinner, but I couldn't figure out how to animate the "border" itself (like the spinner in the newest version of Android). Basically I just used `border` / `border-radius: 50%;` and an infinite CSS animation to rotate the HTML element (0deg -> 360deg): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqiCf

Or do i have to use an "old-school" .gif to get something similar to the "Android L" Spinner?

Comment: Anything's possible, but this one will be very difficult. I see you're pretty close - why don't you add a white circle on top of the blue one in order to control the size of the blue one (though this would only work on white background)? You know, the white one would work like an eraser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'd be possible to achieve using SVG, providing whichever browsers you're targeting support the animations required.

I'd use two components: the partially-opaque "growing circle" effect at the start is one element, and the spinning circular outline is a second element.

The aspect which is impossible to achieve using HTML is having the length of the circular arc changing. In SVG, you can achieve that by using an animated stroke dash array. [Here's an example of that.](http://product.voxmedia.com/2013/11/25/5426880/polygon-feature-design-svg-animations-for-fun-and-profit)

Comment: Thanks, good idea, probably better than just using HTML / CSS. I think browser support for SVG is even better than my take with CSS animations. Haven't worked with SVG yet though, so i'll first need to have a look into it.

Comment: You might find a steep-ish learning curve if you're picking up SVG for the very first time. Here's a basic circle to get you started, though: `<svg><circle cx="15" cy="15" r="13" fill="none" stroke="black" /></svg>`

Comment: I know this was asked awhile ago but here is an HTML, SVG, and CSS version of the spinner. I tried to make it as close as possible. http://codepen.io/nrdobie/pen/jqswe

Comment: @Nick nice work! I didn't think about it at the time, but triggering the "unravelling" effect to end the spinner is another challenge. Might need the Web Animations API for that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time at this moment to make a better example, but this is a little closer.  I tried what Shomz said in the comment, about using a white loader over the blue one.  It isn't perfect, but play around with the timing a bit.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBKJe

Comment: Thanks, I modified your pen a bit and worked with two semicircles overlapping each other. It's similar but unfortunately the overlapping won't really "erase" the color: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cwzvK

Comment: You have the timing down, if you can get the white semicircle to be slightly wider than the blue one, it would take care of the edges.